# How to filter database in table in PHP by year?

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I am new to PHP, I have already created a table with data from 2021 and 2022, but I want to show (filter) only the data that finish on 2022 (so attr_finish_date  == 2022 ???).
I already wrote condition if($p->attr_finish_date == "2022" );, but I don't think it's working.

Can anyone help me?

```
<table border = "1" style="width:100%" id="example">
 <thead>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Target Date</th>
    <th>Finish Date</th>
    <th>information</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    $j=1;
    foreach($data as $p){
        **if($p->attr_finish_date == "2022" );**                                 
           echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$j++."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$p->attr_target_date."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$p->attr_finish_date."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$p->attr_info."</td>";          
           echo "</tr>";                                
     }                      
      ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you should [filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) `$data` or do it in your query. its `if(){}` not `if();`

Comment: 1. Nobody knows what is inside your `attr_finish_date` variable. 2. You should wrap your `<th>` with `<tr>`.

Comment: @user1597430 attr_finish_date contain timestamp data, so like 2022-03-11 or 2021-04-16

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I change to if{$p->attr_finish_date == "2022" };  but return error "Message: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' "

Comment: again not correct if syntax. if `attr_finish_date` is `2022-03-11`, then `== "2022"` wont work you need to parse it to the year, date/create_date()->format etc

Comment: That's because you invented your own `if` syntax. You can visit the official documentation and see samples. For your date question: pass your `Y-m-d` date into `strtotime` and then send the result of that expression into `date` function with an `Y` argument to extract the year.

Comment: show the code that is setting $data; the best thing to do is to change your database query to only include the data you want.  though how to construct an if statement and how to extract the year from a date/datetime are valuable things to learn

Comment: re "attr_finish_date contain timestamp data, so like 2022-03-11", "2022-03-11" is not timestamp data, timestamp data would be more like "2022-03-11 01:02:03" or "2022-03-11 01:02:03.456".  so is it timestamps or just dates?

Comment: @ysth Ah ok, so it is just dates. Can I not change the database query ?, I want to use 1 query and use it in many different tables, so I want to filter it on the PHP table coding.

Comment: sure, you can do that.  you just need to learn how to extract the year from the date to compare, and how to format an if statement.  which people in these comments have provided pointers on.  it is just more efficient (both in your client and in the database server) to only read the data you need

Comment: @ysth Is it complicated coding to filter the year from dates? I read the answers like parse,, strtotime, etc instead of directly correcting my code and showing the working code. (like I said I just learned PHP, so reading documentation and finding a way to apply it is still much more confusing to me than just reading the working code).

Comment: No. If the date is a string, just use `substr($p->attr_finish_date,0,4)`  (substring of the first first four characters) or use `date("Y", strtotime($p->attr_finish_date))`  (convert to timestamp and convert back to 4 digit year).

Comment: @Roemer Thank you, it works. How do I choose your comment as the answer?